# Google Map Not Working in Floating action Menu

Tags: android, google-maps

I put floating action menu in my layout with google map.map show in Frame Layout Floating action Menu work fine But in map i can't perform any action like in map custom marker. Marker not perform click event also no any event perform in map.

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map_i"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
fab:menu_fab_label="Choose an action"
fab:fab_colorNormal="#e0404b"
fab:fab_colorPressed="#e0404b"
fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
fab:fab_showShadow="true"
fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
fab:menu_labels_position="left"
fab:menu_openDirection="up"
fab:fab_shadowColor="#66000000"
fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true">
 <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_email"
    fab:fab_label="Edit an item" />

   <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_whatsapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_whatsapp"
    fab:fab_label="Edit an item"
    fab:fab_size="mini" />
  </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The width and height "FloatingActionMenu" are "match_parent". It is cover all the map. So you can't do any action in map.